# Neo4j and Neovis.js

Tags: javascript, neo4j, vis.js

I was using the Vis.js library to visualize a graph stored as a JSON file. I have now progressed to storing the graph in Neo4j and using Neovis.js library to submit a cypher query to Neo4J and display the results.

However I can't seem to get the original Vis.js functions such as Zoom and Add/Edit node etc to work. I have included the original stylesheet (vis-network.min.css) to display the icons for zoom and add node etc, but can't seem to get it working. Can anyone tell me if neovis.js contains the original functions from vis.js to add/remove nodes and zoom in/out etc as it's supposed to be based on vis.js?

I am a novice programmer and way out of my depth here but any help would be greatly appreciated!

My requirements are to display results of a Cypher Query from Neo4j but also allow the user to add/remove nodes and edges and save the changes from a webpage. Is there a better option to link vis.js to Neo4j directly?

Here is the Neovis.js link: https://github.com/johnymontana/neovis.js

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported by the Neovis.js library currently. However, graph editing would be a useful feature that we should consider adding. Could you [create an issue on Github](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues) to discuss further?